# I need to remove the highlight off of the radtreeview in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, styles, radtreeview

Here is my code. I just need to take the highlight off of the radtreeview. I would just use IsHitTestVisible like I did in the others, but then it does not allow me to click on triggers to extend the nodes.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
 <telerik:RadTreeView x:Name="radTreeView" Margin="8" ItemsSource="{Binding Errors}" Background="Salmon" IsHitTestVisible="True" IsDropPreviewLineEnabled="False" IsDragTooltipEnabled="False" Focusable="False">
            <telerik:RadTreeView.ItemTemplate>
                 <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}" >
                    <Grid Background="Salmon">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>

                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" IsHitTestVisible="False" />

                        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}" Margin="20,0,0,0" BorderBrush="#00000000" BorderThickness="0" Background="Salmon" IsHitTestVisible="False" >
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </Grid>

                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

            </telerik:RadTreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </telerik:RadTreeView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach it from a different angle. You should try changing the following on the TreeViewItem:

- SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey
- SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey

Example:

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
      <Style.Resources>
          <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#FFF"/>
          <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="#000"/>
     </Style.Resources>  
</Style>
```

This will also work on Rad controls. You just need to adjust for a RadTreeViewItem.

Comment: Where exactly should I put this in my code?? When I added it the Exception "Items Collection must be empty before using ItemsSource."

Comment: I think I have implemented it correctly, but it still did not take the highlight off

Comment: Did you make sure to change the TargetType?